# How to code just an input field so that when user "Reopen Closed Tab" after closing the tab, the typed value persists?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, session-state, session-storage

Ok, I know how to persist the value on page refresh or on backward or forward navigation using *sessionStorage*, but I am unable to persist the value after user "Reopen Closed Tab" (by pressing *ctrl+shift+t*) after closing the tab because it creates a new session. Also I don't want to use *localStorage*. I am not sure, but maybe, the answer has something to do with window.history. You tell me. So now my question is, is it possible to write a such a code in pure JavaScript and HTML without using *localStorage* or importing any other API ? If yes, please share the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Also I don't want to use localStorage"_ - why?

Comment: It remains there forever until manually cleared. Its like, if a user closed the tab and changes the localStorage by himself from the console. Then when the page opens again it fetches that funny value that the user wrote by himself. It may disrupt the UI meaning or security.

Comment: Nothing in the browser is secure from tampering. Encrypt the localstorage if that's an issue

Comment: I got the answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can put it to cookie like:

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
var expires = "";
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but incase the user disable the cookies from that domain then what will be the solution ?

Comment: Then the solution will be localStorage

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("myText").value = (window.history.state && window.history.state['pie']) || '';
document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
        window.history.replaceState(
            { ...window.history.state, 'pie': document.getElementById("myText").value },
            document.title
          );
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" onchange="myFunction()" id="myText" value=''>

</body>
</html>
```